# logs being truncated - where?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging

It seems like the access logs on this particular apache2 server I'm running are truncated every day at midnight. I'd rather this be done once a week instead of once a day but am not sure where this is currently being done.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your `Log` directives

Answer (score 3):

Normally log rotation is managed by the [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) utility which run by cron|anacron via the `/etc/cron/daily/logrotate` script.

The logrotate utility has a configuration file `/etc/logrotate.conf` which contains defaults for all logrote jobs. These defaults can be modified by the contents of scripts in `/etc/logrotate.d`.

On CentOS for example `anacron` (via /etc/anacrontab) runs `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` which reads the `/etc/logrotate.conf` directives which are added to/overridden by the contents of the `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`.

Ubuntu is pretty much the same except cron runs the /etc/cron.daily/logrotate script via the directives in `/etc/crontab`.